# window.opener.document not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a weird problem with Internet Explorer
I have a popup that is opened by a base page.

parent.jsp

```
<script>
    function chkYMS(){           
         alert("setYMS:" + document.getElementById('setYMS').value); //setYMS:16.05.2015
         window.open(/common/popup.jsp, 'popFrm');
    }
</script>
<form name="frm" method="post">
    <input name="setYMS"  id="setYMS" type="text" class="inputbox_25" style="width: 135px;"/> 
    <img src="/common/images/icon/c.gif" onClick="chkYMS();" align="absmiddle">
</form>
```

popup.jsp

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
     var getYMS = "";
     //not working ie 8,9,10,11 : document is null or not an object (chrome is working)
     //getYMS = window.opener.document.forms['frm'].elements['setYMS'].value;
     //getYMS = window.opener.document.getElementById('setYMS').value;
     //getYMS = parent.opener.document.getElementById('setYMS').value; 
     //getYMS = window.opener.RceptTransYMS.value;


 </script>
 <form name="popFrm">
 </form>
```

How can I pix it?
I don't want to use window.showModalDialog() 
Can you please provide some help?

Answer (score 0):

Few Resolution Options to give a try:

1. Under the Security Tab in your internet options, click on the Trusted Websites Icon.  Now check the checkbox marked "Enable Protected Mode" and restart internet explorer.
   (please keep in mind that the website in question was a Trusted Website)
2. You can also try something like this,

   **var win = window.open("", "win","width=200,height=100");

   win.document.write('This is the popup window!');

   win.focus();

   win.opener.document.write('This is the source window!');**
3. window.opener is a non-standard property and few browsers doesn't support it. Using window.open(URL,name,specs,replace) instead is a good choice. window.opener won't work in IE under default security level if the child window is from a different domain..